# unit testing auto mapper using moq

Tags: c#, unit-testing, automapper, moq

I have a service method which gets data from the repository and using automapper I am mapping it to the dto.

```
public CustResponse GetCustomer(string id)
{
var repo = _myRepo.GetData(id);
var response = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<CustResponse>(repo.custObj)
                           .Map(repo.addrObj);
return response;
}
```

I have created .map extension method in order to map multiple objects in class to a single dto.

```
public static TDestination Map<TSource, TDestination>(this TDestination destination, TSource source)
{
    return Mapper.Map(source, destination);
}
```

Automapper configuration:

```
m.CreateMap<CUSTOBJ,CustResponse>().ForMember(/*Some Properties*/);
m.CreateMap<ADDROBJ,CustResponse>().ForMember(/*Some Properties*/);
```

Now, I would like to write a unit test case for my `GetCustomer` method. I am not able to do so because my method depends on `Mapper.Map`.

Is there anyway I can move `var response = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<CustResponse>(repo.custObj).Map(repo.addrObj);` to some interface and use the interface object to invoke the action.

In this way, I would be able to `mock` auto mapper interface.

Unit Testing code:

```
var repStub = new Mock<ICustomerRepository>();
var expected = new CustResponse();            
var mockMapper = new Mock<Mapper.Map>(); //Not working
var customer = new CustomerService(repStub.Object);
customer.GetCustomer("data");
```

**Edit:** I am not asking if I should do automapper unit testing or not. My questions my current service method does not allow me to create `moq` objects of `Mapper`. How can I create `IMapper` interface with my implementation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it a good practice to mock Automapper in unit tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39998115/is-it-a-good-practice-to-mock-automapper-in-unit-tests)

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14177455/unit-test-the-automapper-profiles

Comment: @cbp : I don't think it is a duplicate question. What I want is to move my mapper method logic to the interface. As I have an extension method on top of it and I am not able to understand how to invoke it using interface object?

Comment: @Shaggy Don't tightly couple to the static API. register the `IMapper` with your container and inject where it is needed. From there you should be able to easily mock/stub a mapper when testing.

Comment: @Shaggy what platform? Core?

Comment: @Shaggy Also show a test as a [mcve]. Should be able to get help from there

Comment: @Nkosi :  Yes, that's what I wanted to do. I am not able to write an interface for my implementation. I want a method which would allow me to use multiple `.Map` methods on `Mapper` object. I am using `.net 4.6`

Comment: Automapper already has an IMapper interface in the instance API http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Static-and-Instance-API.html

Comment: So you either refactor to use the instance API and inject that or make sure to configure the static API for your tests if coupled to static API.

Comment: @Shaggy check a previous answer I gave in this same space https://stackoverflow.com/a/39868221/5233410